# Call method directly on number

Tags: javascript, oop, methods

I recently implemented a very simple method to extend the base JavaScript Number Class and tried to call it directly on an entered number in the browser console.

```
123.myMethod();
```

But it is not working as expected, it only says: "Invalid or unexpected token"

I was unsure, if I can call Number Methods directly on entered numbers, so I tried standard methods like .toFixed():

```
123.toFixed(1);
```

But this also isn't working.

Only if I write a float, I can call Number methods:

```
123.0.toFixed(1);
```

It also works, if I put the Integer inside brackets:

```
(123).toFixed(1);
```

So my question is:
Why are Integers not implicitly casted to Number and why can't I use Number methods on them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.` tells the JavaScript interpreter to be a decimal point, so it is expecting more numbers. In JavaScript there is only floats, no integers.

Comment: Hmmm... I think I'll go with (123).myMethod() then as explicitly casting like parseInt(123).myMethod() looks a bit ugly ;-)

Comment: `parseInt(123)` is not "explicitly casting" anything. First of all, it's *parsing*. It will turn whatever you give it into a *string* and then it would read it character by character to extract the number value. What you get is *usually* the exact same number but really large numbers can be mangled. Also, you still get a primitive out of it, you don't get a Number object. To do that you'd need to do `new Number(123)` but beware that `new Number(123) !== new Number(123)` because they are *different objects*. `primitiveNumber.myMethod()` also works as you get the implicit conversion into object.